How to load only certain section in Angular without refreshing the menu component?
I have an angular app with below code in app component
<div class="app-container">
  <app-header *ngIf="router.url !== '/'" class="topbar"></app-header>
  <mat-drawer-container class="body-container">
    <mat-drawer mode="side" opened *ngIf="router.url !== '/'" class="side-bar">
      <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </mat-drawer>

    <mat-drawer-content class="main-container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-drawer-content>
  </mat-drawer-container>
</div>

and my router file is as below
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'user',
    component: UserComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  { path: 'student', component: StudentComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];

in the left side bar, i have button which navigates to different component, everything is fine, but the left pane also refreshes when loading the main content. What should i do to fix this?

Quick answer: set the changeDetection property in the @Component decorator for AppSidebarComponent to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush (imported from @angular/core). This will cause the component to be re-rendered only when an @Input changes or the component is manually marked for change detection checking. See the documentation for change detection - skipping subtrees for more info.

If that approach doesn't work for you, you could introduce a second (named) <router-outlet> in your <mat-drawer> so the AppSidebarComponent would be outside the scope of the main <router-outlet>. Your URL will be impacted with this approach (something like /user(outlet2:sidebar). See the documentation for displaying multiple routes in named outlets for more info.

first one didn't work, can you please tell me what exactly i should change in 2nd approach..  i am new to angular

Oh, I see the problem. You have a parent component with *ngIf="router.url !== '/'". That's going to be reevaluated every time the URL changes which will necessarily mark that whole tree as dirty. The sidebar component isn't being refreshed, it's being destroyed and recreated...

You probably don't want to add/remove the sidebar from the template based on the route. Instead, you probably want to open/close the sidebar. Try binding to the opened attribute via  [opened]="router.url !== '/'" (and remove the *ngIf="router.url !== '/'").

i tried this and it didn't help

I figured it out and below is the modified code. hope it will help someone
<app-header *ngIf="router.url !== '/'" class="topbar"></app-header>

<mat-sidenav-container class="main-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    *ngIf="router.url !== '/'"
    #sidenav
    mode="side"
    opened
    class="sidenav"
    [fixedInViewport]="false"
    [fixedTopGap]="0"
    [fixedBottomGap]="0"
  >
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

